# Unexpected token error observed while using jq library in shell

Tags: shell, unix, jq

I have used the below command, and It will get some substring in attribute value.

```
  skipped=$(echo "$value" | jq -f '.[].output | scan("totalSkipped+: [[:digit:]]+")' | sed 's/"//g' )
```

I ran this script in shell through Jenkins job. and observed below error message:

```
/tmp/jenkins7615126817764256878.sh: command substitution: line 30: syntax error near unexpected token `"totalSkipped+: [[:digit:]]+"'
/tmp/jenkins7615126817764256878.sh: command substitution: line 30: `echo "$value" | jq .[].output | scan("totalSkipped+: [[:digit:]]+") | sed 's/"//g' )'
```

I have the entire json file which is stored in $value variable and echo "$value" returned the content of json file but not sure why its not working in jenkins.

I used the same command in jq online tool but It works as expected.

https://jqplay.org/s/7lBj_kDoB3

I'm using jq-1.6 version.

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Enclose jq script in single quotes, this has nothing to do with jq as it seems

Comment: I did that but no luck

Comment: Note that the code in your question and the code in your error message are out-of-sync with each other, since you edited the former but not the latter. Please collect a new error message (don't just edit the error message to match, but actually make the error happen again after fixing the code that's live at runtime and copy-and-paste the new/different message that results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
skipped=$(jq -r '.[].output | scan("totalSkipped: [[:digit:]]+")' <<<"$value")
```

The pipeline is *jq* syntax, so it needs to be inside single quotes so the shell doesn't try to find a separate shell command named `scan`.

No reason for `sed` here -- using the `-r` argument to jq makes it emit raw strings as output, so they don't have syntactic quotes.